# Model combining two tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the tables "item", "payment", "join_payment".

The item has an `id`, the payment has an `id`. The join_payment has the rows `item_id` and `payment_id`.

A payment may contain many items, which would be registered in the join_payment table.

I want to make a log with these items and I am currently doing this in the controller:

```
$log = Array();

$items = item::where("id",Auth::user()->id)->get();

foreach($items as $item){

$join_payment = join_payment::where("item_id",$item->id)->first();

 if(!array_key_exists($join_payment->payment_id,$log){
  $log[$join_payment->payment_id] = payment::where("id",$join_payment->payment_id)->first();
 }
 $log[$join_payment->payment_id][$item->id] = $item;
}
```

Is there a way to pull this out with the models?

Comment: What is the structure you want for this `$log` variable?

Comment: @log The same  as in the function, but instead of doing it with loops in the controller, it is done in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using Eloquent relationships for this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many.  If you call the join table `item_payment` it will be even easier:

```
class Item extends Model {
    public function payments(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Payments::class)
    }
}

class Payment extends Model {
    public function items(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)
    }
}

class ItemPayment extends Model {
    public function item(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class)
    }
    public function payment(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Payment::class)
    }
}
```

Then you can access the data you need in a bunch of ways:

```
$items = Item::all();
foreach($items as $item){
    $item->payments; //returns all payments belonging to this item
}


$payments = Payment::all();
foreach($payments as $payment){
    $payment->items; //returns all items belonging to this payment
}


$itemPayments = ItemPayment::all();
foreach($itemPayments as $itemPayment){
    $itemPayment->item; //the item for this join
    $itemPayment->payment; //the payment for this join
}
```

Sorry for changing your class and table names, but these conventions will make your life a ton easier in Laravel

Answer (score 1):

in your Item model use this

```
public function payment()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Payment','join_payment','payment_id','item_id');
}
```

then in you loop check

```
foreach($items as $item){
   dd($item->payment);
}
```